# cordova run android exited with exit code 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

While running `ionic cordova run android` I got the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.2.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
21 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 20 up-to-date
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.2.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Such problem seems to come from an outdated version of gradle.

#### Step to fix

1. Download [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
2. Update gradle to the latest version
3. Keep android studio open
4. Remove android -> ionic cordova platform rm android
5. Control that the `platforms` folder is empty inside your project
6. run `ionic cordova platform add android`
7. Try again tu run `ionic cordova run android`